# Javascript not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a index.html file that was previously created by DNN (Dot Net Nuke).

I've put a Javascript Slideshow Banner in where there was previously an SWF Slideshow banner. The problem is the javascript is not showing up.

Here's what the problem (i.e. banner not showing) looks like: http://www.drkachooie.ca/index.html

Note: When I upload an html with just the flash banner it shows up (http://www.drkachooie.ca/rice.html), so something must be overlapping it, right?

My question is: How can I adjust my code to make my javascript show up? If someone can check the code out, and see what's wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the javascript (Correction: HTML & CSS) in the body tags of the index.html document:

```
<div id="mhrotator">
<style type="text/css"> #mhrotator img { display:none; } </style>
<img src="images/Bitmap1.jpg" title="Bitmap1" />
<img src="images/Bitmap2.jpg" title="Bitmap2" />
<img src="images/Bitmap3.jpg" title="Bitmap3" />
<img src="images/Bitmap4.jpg" title="Bitmap4" />
<img src="images/Bitmap5.jpg" title="Bitmap5" />
</div>
```

Here's the javascript in the head tags of my index.html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mhrotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/initrotator.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/mhrotator.css" type="text/css" />
```

Currently all the other pages of the website are using the old swf file as my banner. but the index.html file is currently using the javascript (which is not showing up)

Note: If you need any other information, feel free to ask!

Comment: "*Here's the javascript in the body tags of the index.html document:*" - that's not javascript...

Comment: The `style` element should be in the `head` section.

Comment: Your page has a bunch of resources that are not found (404's), and one of your scripts is erroring out... check the dev console and fix

Comment: You are using the wrong jQuery variable. One of your other js files has used `$` for some other library, you need to switch out `$` for `jQuery` in your _initrotator.js_ file

Answer (score -1):

The version that is working has the banner inside of a `div` element that is not being affected by `<style type="text/css"> #mhrotator img { display:none; } </style>` which ***is*** preventing the version that isn't working from showing the images.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting! But if I remove the     
    <style type="text/css"> #mhrotator img { display:none; } </style>, 
The index.html file shows the images without the javascript effect.

Answer (score -1):

I see this error in console :-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mhrotator' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (initrotator.js:1)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:26)
    at HTMLDocument.L (jquery.js:33)
```

Javascript is getting executed before div element mhrotator gets loaded.

Try placing below script tag after `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mhrotator.js">
```

Comment: You said try placing below script tag after "tag"... but which tag are you referring to?